# How to recognize the 2nd edition of Railways Of The World?

Tags: railroad

The 2nd edition includes cards for the Mexico map, which as far as I understand are rather indispensable for the 2 and 3 player variant of the game. My question is: is it possible to differ between the first and second edition on the box's outsite?

Answer (score 3):

Besides for the Mexico variation, the reprint have slightly grayer art and a photo of the game in use on its backside..

Here is the two games for comparison :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aparently, [someone has already asked on BoardGameGeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/608573/how-to-recognize-2nd-edition). As I expected, it is very hard to see.